Question About the Existential Quantifier, $\exists$
I know $\forall$ means a property/relation holds for all elements in the given domain and $\exists$ means it holds for at least one element. I don't understand why one of the quantifiers is specifically all, while the other is ambiguous and could mean it holds for $1$ case or $500$ cases.
I should preface this by saying I just started an intro to proofs class and I have not actually begun writing proofs. So the following assumption may be completely incorrect.
Consider the following two statements:
$$\exists x\in\Bbb{Z}, x\,\text{mod}\,2=0$$
$$\exists x\in\Bbb{Z}, x^2=4$$
These use the same quantifiers but one has infinitely many elements where the statement holds and the other has exactly two. Intuitively I would think this difference is sometimes relevant when writing proofs; however, if it was important I would think there would be notation to represent it.

We care about $\exists$ precisely because it's used in the negation of $\forall$; to negate $\forall$ it doesn't matter how many counter examples exist - just one is needed.

Elaborating on @JürgenSukumaran's comment, the point is that $\forall$ and $\exists$ are dual to each other: $$\neg\forall\neg = \exists\quad\mbox{and}\quad \neg\exists\neg=\forall.$$

Also, let's mention that we do have notation to represent the common case “there exists exactly one”: $∃ ! x, P(x)$ (add an exclamation mark after $∃$). Just $∃$ means “there is at least one”, which is not somehow wrong, there are plenty of cases where you can prove an object exists but saying anything about how many objects you can find is impossible or much harder, or you're simply not interested in that.

Of course, we also sometimes care about how many things satisfy a given predicate, not just whether it's 0 or > 0. But that's a much more sophisticated concept. $\exists$ and $\forall$ are logical primitives without any notion of number. I suppose you could make up a symbol like $\exists_n$ where $\exists_n, x P(x)$ means there are $n$ distinct $x$ satisfying $P(x)$, but that would require building up the theory of natural numbers first. And often we are only interested in $\exists$.

It's also useful for example to prove just $P(5)$, and from that conclude $\exists n, P(n)$ without having to worry about whether there are any other values of $n$ for which $P(n)$ holds.  That's similar to the way that it's useful to be able to prove $P$, and then conclude $P \lor Q$ without having to worry whether or not $Q$ might also be true.

They are dual to each other.
While $∀$ says that $∀x. \varphi(x)$ is true if and only if for all $x$, $\varphi(x)$ is true;
$\exists$ says that $∃x.\ \varphi(x)$ is false if and only if forall $x$, $\varphi(x)$ is false.
So they are both foralls in a sense.
This is also seen in their deduction rules:
$$ \dfrac{\varphi ⊢ \psi}{\varphi ⊢ ∀x.\ \psi} \qquad \text{for $x$ not free in $\varphi$} $$
$$ \dfrac{∃x.\ \varphi ⊢ \psi}{\varphi ⊢ \psi} \qquad \text{for $x$ not free in $\psi$} $$
Of course through the translation $∃ ≡ \neg ∀ \neg$ you could forget about the existential quantifier completely. But that way you can also forget about the universal quantifier ---through $∀ ≡ \neg\exists\neg$---, you can also forget about one of $∧$ or $∨$, etc.

If you care about truth (and let's by now say this means having a proof of something), you only care about  either having a proof, or not; not how many.
Of course it is interesting to have many proofs of the same theorem, it gives a broader view of the topic and many other things; but regarding truth, by definition ---the one I just gave---, it isn't.

You have the rule for the existential flipped. It should be $\cfrac {\varphi \vdash \psi}{\exists x \varphi \vdash \psi}$ where $x$ is not free in $\psi$.

@PW_246 They can be read both ways, bottom up and from top to bottom, as both an introduction and an elimination. This comes from the definition $\exists \dashv weak \dashv \forall$, and that's also why I wrote the existential quantifier above. Of course this is not the usual implementation but it does show the symmetry between the two.

Then why add the restriction that x be not free in $\psi$?

@PW_246 what's the deal? I don't follow.

Am I supposed to read the first one top-down and the second bottom-up? What I’m saying is that as long as $\phi[t/x]$ has $t$ free for $x$ in $\phi$, then $\cfrac{\exists x \varphi \vdash \psi}{\varphi[t/x] \vdash \psi}$ is always valid, regardless of $\psi$, as long as you only read it top-down.

@PW_246 as it says in the first comment they can both be read both top-down and bottom-up! It's quite amazing in my opinion that this is enough. (Although if you know both NK and LK it shouldn't be that surprising.) I didn't write much more in the answer because I didn't think it was relevant for the question and I thought it could clutter but I guess it added confusion. Cheers!

It isn't clear in my first comment I believe. I prefer writing it this way because I associate left-right with top-bottom. And $\exists$ is precisely a left adjoint so I read the rule as $(\Gamma_1 \times \Gamma_2)(\exists_\sigma \ \varphi , \psi) \cong$ $(\Gamma_1 \times \sigma \times \Gamma_2)(\varphi , weak_\sigma \ \psi)$.
